# Multiple Entity managers

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have also posted this question before and I am posting it again as it is not resolved yet.

I am using Symfony2 for my application and I need to create two database connections i.e Read and Write for this I search and found easily that we can create different entity managers and i have created like that :

Making object in controller

```
$emWrite = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager('write');
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
```

when I persist the entity It gives me the following error:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship &#039;
AppBundle\Entity\Follower#user&#039; that was not configured to cascade persist
operations for entity: adeel. Explicitly persist the new entity or configure
cascading persist operations on the relationship. If you cannot find out which
entity causes the problem implement AppBundle\Entity\User#__toString()
to get a clue. (500 Internal Server Error)
```

I have already tried many things like giving persist property in both sides of entities involved.

Comment: I have removed four dead (404) links from this question. I assume that makes the question unanswerable, so I will try to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't related to multiple entity managers but to options that you haven't setted onto your class, fore relationship purpose.

I haven't much details about your entities, but I could suggest you to modify relationship in that way

```
<?php
class User
{
    //...
    /**
     * Bidirectional - One-To-Many (INVERSE SIDE)
     *
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="author", 
                  cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    private $commentsAuthored;
    //...
}
```

Where `cascade={"persist","remove"}` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I am sharing my entities also but I have already tried this but it didnt worked...

Comment: @MuhammadUmair I suppose that sharing entities between two entity manager isn't a great choice and you can't do something like persist onto cascading action....

Comment: I have edited my question and give entities detail please check it and elaborate your answer as i am new to this ...

Comment: @MuhammadUmair: can I ask you a think? Why have you two database?

Comment: @ DonCallisto: I have master , slave databases (write and read) and they are synchronize...

Comment: @MuhammadUmair you didn't provide all entities .... Or do you? Because I don't see `ProfileViewer` entity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16697/discussion-between-muhammad-umair-and-doncallisto)